# Google Chrome scroll freezing while appending ajax content on a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, scrollbar

I have a problem with chrome scrollbar,on Mozilla there is no such a problem.
I have couple of synchronous ajax requests and then some info appending on the page,they need about 2 secs to load.During this time the scrollbar freezes and is not usable,when the ajax end the scroll works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Javascript is completely single-threaded.
>
> If you make multiple AJAX calls, you will receive each response as
>   soon as the server sends it; the order depends on the amount of time
>   that it takes the server to send each reply.
>
> If your code is still running when the server replies, the reply will
>   only be processed after your code finishes.
>
> You should try to load all of the data in a single request.

Source: [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483866/2600707)

I might hit a wall here, in other programming languages you can start a new thread for connections/things like that, if you run multiply threads (kinda like layers) your interface stays the way it is/was.

Answer (score 0):

When you use synchronous AJAX the page stops until ajax finish, so if you want the page not stop, must be asynchronous AJAX call.

> You can see more here:
>   [Documentation AJAX W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is not browser behavior problem.

When you make an synchronous request it means that the the code pending for the response.
Since javascript is a single threaded language (lets ignore web-workers for now),
also the UI processing/manipulation is pending,
and this is why the browser or scroll-bar "stuck".

The reason it works on Firefox is that synchronous calls are deprecated (btw because of the "stuck" behavior), and what you are actually doing there is asynchronous request;
You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests